# QML: keep tooltip visible all the time on the slider

Tags: qt, qml, tooltip

I have a page, containing few buttons and a slider. This page getting dynamically loaded through a loader, which has focus set true. I did customization of slider by following this doc [customizing slider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-slider)

I have attached a tooltip with the Handle of tooltip, basically with given rectangle as handle.
I set tooltip visible property true to make it visible all the time and timeout -1. As per my requirement this tooltip should always visible to user, even though he is interacting with other controls, like button on the same page.
But even though I kept visible property set true, on clicking outside of the slider or interaction with buttons, make tooltip disappear. I also tried with removing "timeout" property, but its default value already -1. So make no sense of keeping or not keeping it in the code.
I also tried that focus property of loader and the page in which this slider reside, to make it visible but its only work with keyboard focus, which I don't required. I tried with MouseArea and its press event handling, to make tooltip visible, but not working.
Why tooltip visible property is not working or making it visible all the time, when it get set true? Basically clicking outside of slider, lose the focus from it, that what I understand.

Thanks in advance for helping out here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what behavior you want, but you might try this property:

```
closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
```

You can look at the other options [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#closePolicy-prop)

Comment: Thanks @mzimmer It worked for me. It did not hit me to go through the all the members of Tooltip and look which can help me. But again, thank you for helping out

Comment: I'm glad that's what you wanted. For future reference, the Qt documentation is excellent; in this case, however, I didn't find what I was looking for in the docs on ToolTip, so I went to its parent Popup and found what I was looking for there. I recommend a similar approach in the future.